# Como matar esse processo de Impressão do mozilla?

Tags: javascript, c#

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso de um código C# que mata esse processo de impressão, ou pelo menos o nome do processo.

Comment: Mas isso que você quer é local, só na sua maquina ou algo para os clientes que acessarem o seu site?

Comment: Na verdade eu realizo teste Automatizado, nosso sistema é especifico para Chrome, porém utilizo o firefox para teste, no chrome quando mando imprimir ele abre uma aba mas no mozilla ele abre essa caixa de impressão preciso dar um kill nela para prosseguir no teste.

Comment: Entendi, eu fiz o seguinte teste aqui, utilizei o comando tasklist(Que lista os processos naquele momento) com o firefox aberto, depois apertei ctrl p para abrir a parte de impressão, e dei outro tasklist e comparei a lista, ela era a mesma, ou seja ele não cria um novo processo para impressão.

Comment: Blz obrigado pela atenção, vou continuar utilizando uma solução alternativa até trocarmos de navegador para testes...vlw Abraço.

Comment: Eu olhei um pouco aqui mas não encontrei, mas quem sabe você encontre, tente olhar no about:config do firefox, lá você consegue mexer nas configurações do firefox, é só colocar about:config na url.